# Wired mouse stops moving vertically but moves horizontaly

Tags: mouse

After restart mouse works for a second moving cursor vertically and horizontally then drops to the bottom of the screen and cannot move vertically anymore.
Tried to disable and re-enable the mouse using xinput disable / enable commands
Updated to latest linux headers.
Another wired mouse works fine.
The mouse that has issues is model Delux M618
It might be that vertical movement is much faster than horizontal but it's hard to tell what's happening.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir, Linux 5.15.0-89-generic